# Proving that the sublevel set of a quadratic function is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

> Let
>
> $$C := \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : 2x^2 \le 1 \}$$
>
> Prove that $C$ is convex.

I started with the definition: for $ x_1, x_2 \in C$

$$ \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 = \dots $$

but didn't make any progress. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: I'd rewrite the set as
$$C = \{x\in{\Bbb R}\mid -1/\sqrt 2\leq x\leq 1/\sqrt 2\} = \left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2};\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right].$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use the fact that the function $f(x)=x^2$ is convex. Then,
$$2(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2)^2 \leq 2\lambda x_1^2 + 2(1-\lambda)x_2^2 \leq \lambda + 1 - \lambda = 1,$$
where the second inequality follows from $x_1,x_2 \in C.$

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), the given quadratic inequality can be rewritten as the following [linear matrix inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_matrix_inequality) (LMI)

$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac 12 & x \\ x & 1\end{bmatrix} \succeq \mathrm O_2$$

whose solution set is a [spectrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrahedron) and, thus, convex.

---

[convex-analysis](/questions/tagged/convex-analysis) [schur-complement](/questions/tagged/schur-complement) [linear-matrix-inequality](/questions/tagged/linear-matrix-inequality) [spectrahedra](/questions/tagged/spectrahedra)